# Significance of $e^\pi$

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, pi, constants

I know that $$\sqrt{e^\pi}=\sqrt[i]{i}$$
which is quite a nice result, and that it is transcendental. Does the constant $e^\pi$ have any other significance? Thanks. I realize this is quite a trivial question, but I'm just curious.

Comment: $e^{\pi}$ has little general significance. It's known as Gelfond's constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant), and some numbers related to it are a little interesting. For example, $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ is almost exactly an integer, and $e^{\pi}-\pi$ is almost exactly 20. And there's some sort of geometric interpretation. But otherwise, no, it's not one of the greatest numbers in terms of significance. Which is to say, yeah, it's actually pretty cool! Numbers are cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $\sqrt[i]{i}$ is in most contexts meaningless. Even the square root of a complex number is generally ill-defined, let alone complex roots. To see the issue, consider that I could also write $e^{3 \pi} = e^{\frac{ 3 \pi i}{i}} = \sqrt[i]{e^{3 \pi i}} = \sqrt[i]{i}$.

Comment: Hmm... good point. So it is literally meaningless?

Comment: In fact I have not understood the identity. I know that $\sqrt{e^{\pi }}=e^{\pi/2}\approx4.81047$. Why must I write $\sqrt{e^\pi}=\sqrt[i]{i}$? What is the sense?

Comment: @A-levelStudent If there’s a standard meaning to this, then I don’t know it. The best I think you can hope for is a construction like the complex logarithm, where you define a function that does a certain kind of thing on a subregion of the plane, not the choice is arbitrary in that there are multiple different functions that do the same thing.

Comment: It multi-valued, not meaningless.

Comment: Saulspatz’s comment notwithstanding, I personally doubt that $e^\pi$ has any unique significance on account of this identity.

Comment: @Sebastiano : $e^\frac{i\pi}{2}=i$ and taking the $i$th root we obtain the identity.